# Failing to build android APK with flutter onesignal package

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, onesignal

I have this error message when I want to build APK using this command: `flutter build apk --release`
I tried the build without the `onesignal` package and every things work fine, the strange thing is there is no problem with this package a week ago before this error appears when I am trying to get an APK
[image]

dependencies in pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_svg: ^0.22.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.5
  provider: ^5.0.0
  http: ^0.13.1
  lottie: ^1.0.1
  url_launcher: ^6.0.3
  webview_flutter: ^2.0.4  
  image_picker: ^0.7.5+2
  flutter_image_slider: ^0.0.2
  stripe_payment: ^1.1.1
  onesignal_flutter: ^2.0.0 # This is package that cause the problem for me
  flutter_html: ^0.8.2 
  page_view_indicators: ^2.0.0
  photo_view: ^0.11.1
  timezone: ^0.7.0
  flutter_native_timezone: ^2.0.0
  instant: ^0.4.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use latest version of onesignam_flutter, https://pub.dev/packages/onesignal_flutter